# Limit google autocomplete results with respective(Mentioned) city only?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to limit the search results that is providing by google only to mentioned in city in a country. Lets say for example I am trying to show only Search results of Banglore in India.

I have tried below snippet

```
 function initialize() {
     var options = {
         componentRestrictions: {
             country: 'in'
         }
     };
     var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
     var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

But I need to have second level of filter(componentRestrictions param) for banglore city, How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Related enhancement request in the issue tracker: [Issue 4433: allow componentRestrictions to filter same components as the geocoding API service](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4433)

Comment: Related enhancement request in the issue tracker: [Issue 8118: london city code only](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8118)

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625056/autocomplete-google-maps-place-by-cities